# Menu is automatically disabled in Google Spredsheet & unable to open html service popup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've one project in which Google spreadsheet is used. In Google Spreadsheet I've created a custom menu using Google App Script which consists of sub menu in it. After clicking on particular menu one html service popup appears. The same spreadsheet is shared among some email ids. Some worksheets in the spreadsheet are shared with view permission to some users.

From last 2 days, for one of the email id menu got disabled automatically and even after clicking on the menu html service popup didn't appear. Same functionality is working fine for other users who have edit permission.

There is as such no co-relation between the code and permission of user because same code as well as functionality was working fine from last 3 months.

Any suggestion for the same.

Comment: Go to the Apps Script Issue tracker, and search for your issue.  If this issue has not been reported, you should report it.  [Link to Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: @SandyGood: Thank you. The issue is reported on issue tracker.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the issue.  I don't know if there is a "work around" for it.  You could make this issue know in the Apps Script group also, and maybe get some information there.  [Link to Apps Script group](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)  What is the link to the post on Issue Tracker?

Comment: @SandyGood: Link to the post on Issue Tracker: [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6298&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)

Answer (score 0):

Only users who have permission to edit a spreadsheet, document, or form can run its bound script. Collaborators who have only view access cannot open the script editor, although if they make a copy of the parent file, they become the owner of the copy and will be able to see and run a copy of the script.

Ref: [Scripts Bound to Google Sheets, Docs, or Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)

Comment: The same functionality was working fine with that user from last 3 months. Spreadsheet is shared with edit permission where as some worksheets are shared with view permission. So menu is disabled in tab where there is view permission.

Comment: You can try to open the script code and execute as the user. Could be some permissions problem

Comment: I've written one test function in bounded script to spreadsheet to invoke permission but that didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem where a custom menu that I created wasn't displayed when I was on someone else's computer. Clicking on the menu item to open the script editor didn't work either (no new tab was opening). I was in Firefox, I opened it in Chrome and it worked.